# Indent with two spaces in text request

Tags: paw-app

When using Paw for Elasticsearch the JSON editor is very hard to use to the the structure of requests. For some reason the text input is using four spaces for tabs, while most (all?) JSON documents are 2 (even Paw defaults is 2 spaces for JSON responses).

Any way to fix this? I know you can click "JSON" and then go back to Text again, but it's quite a tedious work flow.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't possible yet to change the indent size and other text input params for the text view… we should be working on it. Sorry!